# C# regex finding the number of captured group

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Suppose this pattern for replacing all URLs in string

```
string domains = "(gl|me|com|ir|org|net|edu|info|me|ac|name|biz|co|pro|ws|asia|mobi|tel|eu|in|ru|tv|cc|es|de|ca|mn|bz|uk|us|au)";

string pattern = @"([\n ]|^)?(((https?|ftp)://)?(www\.)?([\w\d-]+\.)+" + domains + @"([/][\w\d_~:?#@!%$&'()*+,;=`\[\]\.\-]+)*)([\n ]|$)?";
```

I want to replace all URLs with `_URL_` tag but keep both the delimiters in left and right sides of the string.

As i know, `$1` refers to `([\n ]|^)?` at the beginning of the pattern but i couldn't find the correct number for `([\n ]|^)?` at the end of pattern!

```
Regex.Replace(data, pattern, "$1_URL_$?"); // what should be replaced by ?
```

I tested for $2-$8 and no one was correct.

Is there any specific rule for such a situations?

Comment: *[\w\d_* There's no need in `_` since `\w` already includes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need the group that matches the full URL, convert all inner parenthesis into [non-capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html): `()` to `(?:)`. You may also want to integrate the domains directly into the pattern:

```
([\n ]|^)?((?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?(?:www\.)?(?:[\w\d-]+\.)+(?:gl|me|com|ir|org|net|edu|info|me|ac|name|biz|co|pro|ws|asia|mobi|tel|eu|in|ru|tv|cc|es|de|ca|mn|bz|uk|us|au)(?:[/][\w\d_~:?#\@!%$&'()*+,;=`\[\]\.\-]+)*)([\n ]|$)?
```

The front anchor then is captured into `$1` and the rear anchor in `$3`. Or convert remaining URL in group `$2` as well into a non-capturing group, if you like.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/BYkgtm/1)

Answer (score 1):

From your requirement it doesn't seem you need to capture the remaning groups, so you can use non capturing groups for them.

Try this:

```
string pattern = @"([\n ]|^)?(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?(?:www\.)?(?:[\w\d-]+\.)+" + domains + @"(?:[/][\w\d_~:?#@!%$&'()*+,;=`\[\]\.\-]+)*)([\n ]|$)?";
```

and

```
string domains = (?:gl|me|com|ir|org|net|edu|info|me|ac|name|biz|co|pro|ws|asia|mobi|tel|eu|in|ru|tv|cc|es|de|ca|mn|bz|uk|us|au)
```

and then you can simply use the `$2` for the second group

Moreover, I would suggest you to simply use one capture group and replace it with `_URL_`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/UjyOKU/2